# Thymeleaf as Template Engine in Spring Starter Mail

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm switching from Velocity to Thymeleaf and I'm trying to find an example of a template with absolute URLs.

Everything I find says to use `WebContext`, but tying my service to `HttpRequestServlet` and `HttpResponseServlet` seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples are taken from the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html):

> Absolute URLs allow you to create links to other servers. They start
>   by specifying a protocol name (http:// or https://)
>
> `<a th:href="@{http://www.thymeleaf/documentation.html}">`
>
> They are not modified at all (unless you have an URL Rewriting filter
>   configured at your server):
>
> `<a href="http://www.thymeleaf/documentation.html">`

Comment: Is there a better practice of generated the URL dynamically?